# Live data from MySQL with highchart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I found this Highchart live data example [Live data](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data). I try to use my own data which is come from MySQL so, I change the `$y` in `live-server-data.php` to receive the data after use function `fetch_assoc()`.

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```js
 var chart; // global
      
      function requestData() {
       $.ajax({
        url: 'live-server-data.php', 
        success: function(point) {
         var series = chart.series[0],
          shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20
      
         chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);
         
         // call it again after one second
         setTimeout(requestData, 1000); 
        },
        cache: false
       });
      }
       
      $(document).ready(function() {
       chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
         events: {
          load: requestData
         }
        },
        title: {
         text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
         tickPixelInterval: 150,
         maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
         minPadding: 0.2,
         maxPadding: 0.2,
         title: {
          text: 'Value',
          margin: 80
         }
        },
        series: [{
         name: 'Random data',
         data: []
        }]
       });  
      });
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php 

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql_1 = "SELECT SensorData AS power FROM $tbname where SensorID = '1'";

$result_1=$conn->query($sql_1);
while($row = $result_1->fetch_assoc()){
    $y = $row['power'];
}

$conn->close();

 header("Content-type: text/json");
 multiplied by 1000.
 $x = time() * 1000;
 $ret = array($x, $y);
 echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```

The graph is moved but it not shows any data.

[image]

So I press F12 on Chrome Browser and I found this thing.

[image]

I think `"14.600"` may be the cause of my problem. Please tell me if you know the solution to solve this problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: That's a ton of  code to read through with very little context. Can you edit to remove any code that is not directly causing the error? Also you might want to try to just hard-code the json being used so that we see what is going on with the data. We don't know what's in your mysql database!

Comment: The code is edited, thank for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the graph required an `array` that contains numeric values in it. In your case one value is numeric but another one is string so convert all the values to numeric i.e. either integer or float. (Float is preferred here) and pass that array to the graph.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My graph is worked now, just convert those 2 data to float by `floatval()` then it changed from string to numberic.

Comment: Cheers !! Enjoy the coding

Comment: I have some question, is it possible to use multiple `$.ajax` in one page ?
I try to add more graph but the 2nd graph, 3rd graph not response with my page. I already chaged `url` of `$.ajax` but it doesn't work for 2nd and 3rd graph.

Comment: Did not get you ?